# IntelliJ: how to switch color schema with a shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea

I have two different color schemas for the editors (Solarized Dark and Light) and I would like to be able to switch with a shortcut. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (that's the back quote - top left of keyboard) to open a popup menu that allows you to switch color schema, code style schema, keymap or look and feel. Note that the numbers in the popup can be used make a selection. You can remap its shortcut in *Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymap > Main Menu > View > Quick Switch Schema*.

Natively this will take 3 key sequences:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (open menu)
2. <kbd>1</kbd> (select "switch color schema"
3. <kbd>#</kbd> (select scheme)

If this is something you do a lot and want to do make it even more efficient (although I do not think the above is too complex), you can record a macro (Edit > Macro) to  make the change. You can then map it to a shortcut in the Keymap settings. You'd have to record two macros, one for each of the two schemes.

Comment: I often need to switch the "UI Theme" and the "Editor Theme" at the same time. At day, set them both to Default, and at night set them both to Dracula. I tried to record it as a macro, but none was recorded. Is there any way to put a button that toggles them on the toolbar or menu item on the main menu?

Answer (score 0):

You could also "double shift" and then type "Theme"